# CSS body Background Centered to be aligned with content

Tags: css, xhtml, background-image

I want to put a Background image centered in the body (backgroundPosition). And then  I want  all the content(text, tables....) I will add to the page to be aligned with the background, for example, If I zoom the Page, the proportions Background-Content should be respected.

I tried almost everything and I don't know if Its possible, I know if I use position top-left for background position and then content in float:left proportions will be respected, but If I want background centered?

Comment: I already centered my background, the question is how to add content in the page in a way that content doesn't move depending browsers, zoom...etc. 
for example, if I have a cell from a table surrounding an image(from the background), I want the proportions to remain. If I zoom I would like that the image remains inside this cell.

for a background-position top left, the proportions are respected but I cant find a way to do the same with background centered

Answer (score 2):

In the CSS:

```
background-position:center center;
```

That's not cutting it? Maybe you could put up a test page somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for the background image to move as you scale the page you'll have to use javascript.

If javascript is an option for you, you'll be able to get the dimensions of the browser window, and calculate the center point and position the background accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
background:url(path-here) center center;
```